# Error "integer expression expected" in script

Tags: bash

```
WBINFO="/usr/bin/wbinfo -t"
TMP="/tmp/winbind"
RESTART="/sbin/service winbind restart"
TXT="failed"


$WBINFO > $TMP
TARGET='cat $TMP |grep $TXT | wc -l'

if [ "$TARGET" -eq "1" ];
then
$RESTART
else
echo good

fi
```

I get this error:

```
line 10: [: cat $TMP |grep $TXT | wc -l: integer expression expected
```

Answer (score 3):

Single-quoted strings don't expand `$FOO` into the contents of the variable `FOO`.  Use double-quotes (`"`).

Further, it looks like you're wanting the contents of `TARGET` to be the output of the `cat` command.  If so, you probably want:

```
TARGET=$(cat "$TMP" | grep "$TXT" | wc -l)
```

Even further further, `cat file | grep pattern` is suboptimal - `grep` knows how to take files as arguments to parse rather than invoking `cat`, which is an whole other process to spawn.  You probably really want:

```
if [[ $( grep -c "$TXT" "$TMP" ) -eq 1 ]]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TARGET='cat $TMP |grep $TXT | wc -l'
```

This assigns the literal string `'cat $TMP |grep $TXT | wc -l'` to the variable `$TARGET`.

It looks like what you want is the output of the command, which requires backticks:

```
TARGET=`cat $TMP |grep $TXT | wc -l`
```

or, if you have a reasonably modern shell, the `$(...)` syntax:

```
TARGET=$(cat $TMP |grep $TXT | wc -l)
```

Furthermore, that command can be simplified considerably, from the above to this:

```
TARGET=$(grep $TXT $TMP | wc -l)
```

to this:

```
TARGET=$(grep -c $TXT $TMP)
```

Finally, the `$TARGET` variable can be eliminated altogether if you change the `if` statement from this:

```
if [ "$TARGET" -eq "1" ];
```

to this:

```
if [ $(grep -c "$TXT" "$TMP") = 1 ];
```

Or you can use `[[` ... `]]` rather than `[` ... `]` (it's preferred for bash).

Or, if you only care whether the pattern occurs at all (rather than requiring it to appear exactly once):

```
if grep -q "$TXT" "$TMP";
```

For that matter, you can eliminate the `$TMP` file as well; I'll leave that as an exercise. 8-)}

Consult the documentation for `grep` to see what the options do. (The `-c` option tells it to print the number of matches, `-q` prints nothing but still sets the status to indicate whether the pattern was found).

Note that I also added quotation marks around the variable references, which is good practice if there's any possibility that their values might contain any special characters.

Comment: Good answer, but I would like to point out that (though not of apparent utility in this case) the question's script explicitly tested for the number of matches to be exactly 1, not to run `$RESTART` if there were somehow two or more matches in the file (:

Comment: Great answer, but I assume you meant `-q` -- as you mention in the text below -- rather than `-s` in your last code snippet; also, the `,` shouldn't be there. Finally, it's also worth mentioning that in bash `[[` is preferred over `[`.

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks. I'm seriously considering paying more attention to what I write.

Comment: :) Thanks for updating; the `-s` is still there, though.

Comment: I see, but it looks like the `-s` in `if [ $(grep -s "$TXT" "$TMP") = 1 ];` shouldn't be there, either; I assume you meant `if [ $(grep -c "$TXT" "$TMP") = 1 ];`. (If you _also_ meant to use `-s` to silently ignore errors stemming from a non-existent input file, you'd have to double-quote the command substitution to prevent the `[...]` from breaking, or use `[[...]]` instead.)

Comment: @mklement0: D'oh! Fixed, please re-check, and thanks.

Comment: Looks good - thanks for being committed to getting this right.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
TARGET='cat $TMP |grep $TXT | wc -l'
```

to

```
TARGET=$(cat $TMP |grep $TXT | wc -l)
```

or

```
TARGET=`cat $TMP |grep $TXT | wc -l`
```