# Integer expression expected error with shell script

Tags: shell

im a real noob with this, sorry if this is a stupid question

heres a clip of the code

(first line is line #259, last line is #263)

```
if [ $col -le 6 ]
then
echo -e "\t\t\033[91;4m
$paragraph\033[0m"
elif ! [ $col -le 12 ]
```

when i run it this is what i get when i run it

```
./checker.sh: line 259: [: .",: integer expression expected
./checker.sh: line 263: [: .",: integer expression expected
```

when i looked up this error it said to make sure there is a space in between the bracket and i have a bracket. im not sure what else to do.

Comment: Check the value of `$col`. It almost certainly isn't what you expect it is. (And, in fact, would appear that it is `.\",` somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "integer expression expected" in script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716389/error-integer-expression-expected-in-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error messages are informative if you study how to read them.

Let's run three examples:

```
$ col="1"; [ $col -le 6 ]
$ col=""; [ $col -le 6 ]
bash: [: -le: unary operator expected
$ col="a"; [ $col -le 6 ]
bash: [: a: integer expression expected
```

Of these three, you obtained the message: "integer expression expected".  That means that your `col` is not an integer.

To reproduce the message you see, we set `col=' .",'`:

```
$ col=' .",'; [ $col -le 6 ]
bash: [: .",: integer expression expected
```

Comment: that's just the part of the script that giving me the error. would it help if i put the entire script in?

Comment: You could just look for the part that sets the value of `col`.  If it is not clear where that is, then run `bash -x checker.sh`.  This will produce a lot of diagnostic output.  Search through the output for where `col` is set and look for why it is set to the wrong value.

Comment: col=()  which means it's set to nothing if I'm correct

Comment: Yes, that is right.  More precisely, `col=()` means that it is set to an empty _array_.  For the code shown in the question to work, you need `col` set to a number.